# Unable to use "embed PDF & EPS (experimental)" option in Scribus 1.4.1

Tags: 12.04, latex, scribus

I am planning to use Scribus for the preparation of scientific posters. I especially like the LaTeX frame option that Scribus has, which let's me use Latex directly in the poster.

However, when I export my poster to PDF, the LaTeX fonts look less sharp than the other parts of the document that are typed directly into Scribus text boxes. I have read in sevaral places that the option to use to get really sharp LaTeX output is "embed PDF & EPS (experimental" from the PDF export page. However, that check-box is greyed out for me. I then read that you need [Podofo](http://podofo.sf.net) to get this option. However, as far as I can tell, I already have Podofo among my packages (writing `sudo apt-get remove libpodofo0.` and using tab completion yields `libpodofo0.8.0  libpodofo0.9.0`). 
Furthermore, `sudo apt-get install libpodofo` does nothing, the option is still greyed out.

Does anyone have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving some helpful advice from the Scribus mail list, I found the solution to my problem. The version of Scribus in the official Ubuntu repositories does not have the Embed PDF/EPS option enabled. Instead, the Scribus repositories from http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Debian#Ubuntu_Oneiric_Ocelot_.28oneiric_or_11.10.29 need to be enabled. After downloading the updated Scribus package with the Oneiric repositories activated, PDF/EPS embedding works.